# Do values stored in keystore persist even after an app updates?

Tags: android, android-file, android-keystore

I'm planning to save sensitive information on the keystore, won't it be erased after updating the app?

Comment: -sensitive information on the keystore- are you referring to the keystore used to sign the application? Or are you referring to SharedPreferences?

Comment: I assume you mean the AndroisKeystore? And no it won't, but there are other things you have to be on the lookout for. The exact behavior is different on different api levels but generally your keys will be erased if the user sets or removes a pin lock or other security measures.

Comment: And there is no way to get around that, your app just has to be built to work with that. If you use a normal keystore, for example one which you just save in your application private directory you won't have any of those problems. However that way you can't take advantage of a secure element or all the other special features the AndroisKeystore has.

Comment: @DevTest I think he is taking about actual Keystores. I guess he means the AndroisKeystore in particular.

Comment: I'm referring to the keystore used in this tutorial: http://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/

Comment: "but generally your keys will be erased if the user sets or removes a pin lock or other security measures." Will you be able to provide documents to prove this? Please present this as an answer and I will accept it and upvote it if you do. @XaverKapeller